# Running RSpec with Ruby 1.9.1/Rails 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been trying to get RSpec running under Ruby 1.9, and my tests just aren't running.  Here's my trace:

```
matt@matt-desktop:~/Development/my_app$ sudo rake spec --trace
(in /home/matt/Development/my_app)
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute spec
```

And that's it, nothing happens.

Here's the appropriate gems:

```
cucumber (0.3.11, 0.3.9)
rails (2.3.2)
rake (0.8.7)
rspec (1.2.6)
rspec-rails (1.2.6)
test-unit (2.0.2, 1.2.3)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to uninstall test-unit 2.0.2, Rspec doesn't load 1.2.3 properly if it exists.

Comment: Hmm, bizzare.  Looks like that fixed it though.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I had the exact some problem when I upgraded!

Answer (score 0):

Its sometimes difficult when you do a `sudo gem update` without thinking all the messes we have with that newer version of test-unit..